# Convert readable query to Elasticsearch query

Tags: go, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a headache trouble with Elasticsearch query.

I wrote Go code with follow function:

Step 1. Receive readable query from user
Step 2. Convert this readable query to Elasticsearch query
Step 3. Excute this Elasticsearch query to response for user

For example:

After step 1, I received this query like below

```
((camp_id = 'elasticsearch' AND title = 'abc') OR (camp_id = 'search' AND title = 'test') OR camp_id = 'ok') AND city = 'Bath' NOT authors = 'radu gheorge'
```

In step 3, I want to convert this query to Elasticsearch query like below

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "bool" : { 
                    "should": [
                        {
            "bool" : { "must": [
              { "match": { "camp_id": "Elasticsearch" }},
              { "match": { "title": "abc" }}                         
            ] }
          },
          { 
            "bool" : { "must": [
              { "match": { "camp_id": "search" }},
              { "match": { "title": "test" }} 
            ] }
          },
          {
            "match": {"camp_id": "ok"}
          }               
                    ] 
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {"city": "Bath"}
            } 
       ],
             "must_not": { "match": {"authors": "radu gheorge" }}  
         }
     }
 }
```

Originally, I think I can split string at `OR` or `AND` but when the query from user become more complexly, this ideal is impossible.

I am beginner in Elasticsearch.

Comment: If you are using latest elasticsearch then I'll tell you to use translate API, for now, you can check it out https://github.com/lmangani/elasql

Comment: Yes i am using lastest ES. Please help. Give me some example please

Comment: Did you check it ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/sql-translate.html

Comment: Let’s me check. Thanks sir